Does Numpy matrix multiplication completely avoids loops in vectorized codes and how it is actually implemented at processor level?
Numpy methods to calculate the sum or product of two vectors for element wise are faster than the normal unvectorized code implementation using loops and iterating over the arrays. Be that, I want to know the under hood process that takes place in the vectorized numpy method.
For example:
         The code below gives the dot product of two same dimensional array.First, iteration method is used.Then the vectorized numpy method is used.


       Fascinatingly, the time of execution for normal iterative process is around **35ms** and for numpy method is around 0.2ms.

Take a look at the code........
# Dot product 
import time 
import numpy 
import array 

# 8 bytes size int 
a = array.array('q') 
for i in range(100000): 
    a.append(i); 

b = array.array('q') 
for i in range(100000, 200000): 
    b.append(i) 

# classic dot product of vectors implementation 
tic = time.process_time() 
dot = 0.0; 

for i in range(len(a)): 
    dot += a[i] * b[i] 

toc = time.process_time() 



#using numpy method
n_tic = time.process_time() 
n_dot_product = numpy.dot(a, b) 
n_toc = time.process_time() 




So my doubt is that what happens internally at the processor level when numpy code is implemented and normal code is implemented.
How come elements are accessed from arrays without iteration in case of numpy?

numpy is open source so look at the code to understand what happens behind the scenes

Your Python loop is horribly inefficient because it is executed by an interpreter (optimizing nothing at runtime), dot is a dynamic reference-counted object as well as i (variable-sized non-native integer) so access to this are far more expensive than native variables (fixed-size and not dynamic objects nor reference counted). Besides, operation like a[i] are typically as expensive as a function call (which is pretty expensive).

Python is really not designed for performance, but libraries like Numpy can do a relatively good job thanks to vectorization (i.e. calling functions implemented in native languages).

On the other hand, Numpy typically calls a BLAS library (e.g. OpenBLAS) which is implemented in C, possibly parallel, and highly optimized since decades by clever developers (some part of the code is even written in assembly to be nearly optimal). Note though that the Numpy array is first converted to a Numpy array with a different representation. Also note that this BLAS operation tends to be memory-bound nowadays. Finally, note that BLAS libraries (indirectly) use SIMD-instructions to be fast (impossible directly in Python).

If you write the same naive loop in any compiled native language like C, C++, Fortran, Rust, etc. I expect the loop should to be at least 10 times faster (assuming you use compilation flags for producing efficient programs). With the best compilation flags, it should be close to the speed of Numpy and certainly about 100 times faster on most machines.

nice insights. Thank you for sharing.
